# Connecting to MSSQL 2016 with pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, ipython, sql-server-2016

When i connect using the code

```
import pymssql
import pandas as pd

## instance a python db connection object- same form as psycopg2/python-mysql drivers also
conn = pymssql.connect(server="SGRD-THTAN\\THSERVER", user="sa",password="thisIsMe123", database='Feedback')  # You can lookup the port number inside SQL server.
```

I got the error as below:

[image]

How should I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The error code 18456 means that authentication failed.

It looks like Python is mangling the error message a bit - the error message should have a `severity` and a `state` (not two `severity` values)- on the assumption that the second `severity` (`9`) is in fact the `state` value, [this table](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2006/02/21/understanding-login-failed-error-18456-error-messages-in-sql-server-2005/) suggests that the problem is that you have a bad password.